# Generic formula for the power of a finite sum (aka distributive law)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is there a nice formula or expanded out formula for the generic sum 
\begin{align*}
\left( \sum_{i = 1}^n |A_i|
 \right)^p?
\end{align*}
I was unsure what to search for. Expanded out, this leads to a sum of $n\cdot p$ terms with a lot of mixed-up stuff powers and stuff. Perhaps one could just apply the distributive law repeatedly to end up with a formula?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to leave an answer.